# Blueimp File upload-- insert form data into multiple database tables

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have two database tables namely, `photos`, `albums`. I am able to upload photos and insert form data into both tables at once which is okay.

**The problem I have is that,**

when I upload e.g, 5 photos, 5 rows are created into each table-- each row for each photo.

**What I want is that,**

5 rows should be created in the `photos` table **but only one row** should go into `albums` table. The `photos` table has `foreign key` to `albums` table.

**Here is my code below:**

The `index.php` which extends the `UploadHandler` handler has the following code:

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'delete_type' => 'POST',
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_user' => 'username',
    'db_pass' => 'password',
    'db_name' => 'test',
    'db_table' => 'photos'

);

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

    protected function initialize() {
        $this->db = new mysqli(
            $this->options['db_host'],
            $this->options['db_user'],
            $this->options['db_pass'],
            $this->options['db_name']

        );
        parent::initialize();
        $this->db->close();
    }

protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
    $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
    $file->description = @$_REQUEST['description'][$index];
}

protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
    $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
            $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
        );

        if (empty($file->error)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
                .' VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisss',

                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description,
            );
            $query->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;

            //LABEL: PROBLEM BLOCK BEGINS
            /*Here, I am attempting to insert only row in the albums table 
             for each batch of photos I upload. So even if I upload 5 photos 
             into the photos table, only one row should be created in the albums table*/


            $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO `albums` (`album_title`, `album_description`)'
                .' VALUES (?,?)';
            $query2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
            $query2->bind_param(
                'ss',

                $file->title,
                $file->description,
            );
            $query2->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id; 

            //LABEL: PROBLEM BLOCK ENDS
        }

        return $file;
    }


}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($options);

?>
```

In the code above, I have commented block of code as

```
//LABEL: PROBLEM BLOCK BEGINS

...

//LABEL: PROBLEM BLOCK ENDS.
```

The code above works to insert same number of rows in both `photos` table and `albums` table. I need help with the `PROBLEM BLOCK` in order to create only one row in `albums` table for each batch of `photos` I upload in photos table.

Comment: Maybe this is a change you made for the question, but I think second_table shouldn't have single quotes around it?

Comment: @astrangeloop, yes you are right. I have edited and removed the single quotes from `second_table`

Comment: I have renamed `first_table` as `photos` and `second_table ` as `albums` to make the idea of the question clearer and specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself. I added a `unique id` column to the `album` table and I added the value of the `unique id` as `hidden` field on the upload form so it became like this

**the album table**

```
CREATE TABLE album (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  album_title varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  album_description text,
  special_album_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (special_album_id)
)
```

**In the upload form, I added**

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "special_album_id[]" value= "<?php echo $variable-data; ?>">
```

You will need to create your own function to get the variable `$variable-data` which will be different for each new photo upload.

With this, the `CustomUploadHanler.php` will send queries to insert multiple rows in the `album` table but the table will accept only one row for each batch of photos uploaded. Perhaps there is a better solution out there but this worked for me for now.

Also do the following changes in the code in the OP.

**change the:**

```
protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
    $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
    $file->description = @$_REQUEST['description'][$index];
}
```

**to**

```
protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
    $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
    $file->description = @$_REQUEST['description'][$index];
    $file->special_album_id = @$_REQUEST['special_album_id'][$index];
}
```

**Then in the PROBLEM BLOCK, change:**

```
$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO `albums` (`album_title`, `album_description`)'
            .' VALUES (?,?)';
        $query2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
        $query2->bind_param(
            'ss',

            $file->title,
            $file->description,
        );
```

**to**

```
$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO `albums` (`album_title`, `album_description`, `special_album_id`)'
            .' VALUES (?,?,?)';
    $query2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
    $query2->bind_param(
        'sss',

         $file->title,
         $file->description,
         $file->special_album_id

    );
```

That's it; we are done. Hope this helps someone